# Overloading QDebug in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qdebug

In view.h file :

```
friend QDebug operator<< (QDebug , const Model_Personal_Info &);
```

In view.cpp file :

```
QDebug operator<< (QDebug out, const Model_Personal_Info &personalInfo) {
    out << "Personal Info :\n";
    return out;
}
```

after calling :

```
qDebug() << personalInfo;
```

It is suppose to give output : `"Personal Info :"`

but it is giving an error :

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'qDebug()() << personalInfo'
```

Comment: Jyo, please do not add "solved" or a solution to your question... post any solutions as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header:

```
class DebugClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DebugClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    int x;
};

QDebug operator<< (QDebug , const DebugClass &);
```

And realization:

```
DebugClass::DebugClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    x = 5;
}   

QDebug operator<<(QDebug dbg, const DebugClass &info)
{
    dbg.nospace() << "This is x: " << info.x;
    return dbg.maybeSpace();
}
```

Or you could define all in header like this:

```
class DebugClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DebugClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    friend QDebug operator<< (QDebug dbg, const DebugClass &info){
        dbg.nospace() << "This is x: " <<info.x;
        return dbg.maybeSpace();
    }

private:
    int x;
};
```

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the current answer does the trick, there's a lot of code in there that's redundant. Just add this to your `.h`.

```
QDebug operator <<(QDebug debug, const ObjectClassName& object);
```

And then implement like so in your `.cpp`.

```
QDebug operator <<(QDebug debug, const ObjectClassName& object)
{
    // Any stuff you want done to the debug stream happens here.
    return debug;
}
```

Comment: You have suggested exactly the same that I've done. You have just written the comment line instead of my `dbg.nospace()`

Comment: The number of lines is very different, other than that, sure, it's the same @t3ft3l--i